# Hashed passwords displays weirdly

Tags: c#

I've ran into a curious behaviour when trying to hash a string password and then display the hash in console.

My code is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string password = "password";

        ConvertPasswordToHash(password);

    }

    private static void ConvertPasswordToHash(string password)
    {
        using (HashAlgorithm sha = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

            string hashText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);

            Console.WriteLine(hashText);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                sb.Append((char)item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb);
        }
    }
```

The problem is two fold:

1. The hashTest and sb contain different values (both are 32 characters long before outputting) and 2) Console outputs are even stranger. They are not 32 characters in length and second the outputs are slightly different:

[image]

When examining the strings before outputting them, I've noticed that hashText contains for instance \u0004, which could be a unicode character of some sort while sb does not contain that at all (that is before outputting the values into the console).

My questions are:

1. Which way is the correct way of getting a string of chars from the provided array of bytes?
2. Why are the console outputs different but only so slightly? It does not look like it is the fault of using the wrong Encoding.
3. How do I output the correct hash (32 symbols) into the console? Ive tried adding '@' before the strings to cancel any possible carriage returns etc... Pretty much without any result.

Maybe I am missing something obvious. Thank you.

Comment: You could try base64 encoding the result. Keep in mind the hash is a number and not text

Comment: Slighty off-topic, but using SHA256 for passwords is a bad practice. Use a proper password hashing function instead.

Comment: Why would you be trying to show password hashes to anyone?  Just because a hash is more secure than a plain text password doesn't mean you should be any more liberal in showing it to others.

Comment: @Servy of course I don’t want to do this in production. I did not feel it was necessary to state. I was just playing around with hashes and stumbled upon this.

Comment: @Alejandro Which algorithm would you suggest using then?

Comment: Any algorithm specifically designed for password storage will do. .NET has a PBKDF2 built-in implementation, bcrypt is another common one, or newer alternatives like Argon2, for example. Any general purpose hash like MD5, SHA1, any SHA2 or SHA3 are bad for passwords because they're *fast*. Have a look here for more info: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct logic should be as follows:

```
private static void ConvertPasswordToHash(string password)
{
    using (HashAlgorithm sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            sb.Append(item.ToString("x2"));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);
    }
}
```

`ToString("x2")` formats the string as two hexadecimal characters.

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QkREkX

Another way is just to represent your `byte[]` array as a base 64 string, no `StringBuilder` required.

```
byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(result));
```